# Jenkins JIRA Plugin issue

Tags: jenkins, jira

Curently, Jenkins JIRA is polluting the comments in JIRA page, especially with matrix builds.

We had an issue with a couple of user comments and many hudson comments.

Every build, it records the changes.

Any idea to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin), user has an option to turn updates on and off in Post-build Actions settings.

To turn off, make sure that there's no check mark set at "Updated relevant JIRA issues"

[image: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/20070312/jobConfig.png]

Comment: With newer versions of Jenkins, this option can be found after pressing the "Add Post-build Actions" button.